# how can I return to the previous page in Django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm Prety new in Django. I want to know how to return to the previous page from **view** to **template** without taking *path* or *url*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a duplicate but

Try this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def someview(request):
   ...
   return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```